# Navigation is not showing on iPad

Tags: html, css, ipad, ios-simulator

[My website](http://examples.iamwebsitedeveloper.com/john/) is working fine on every browser, but the navigation is not showing on iPhone and iPad!

```
nav#headerNav{
padding: 0;
float: right;
margin-top:-40px;
display: block;
width: 671px;
/* Background color */
background: #094174; /* Show a solid color for older browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#094174, #0E6399);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#094174, #0E6399);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#094174), to(#0E6399)); /* older webkit syntax */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#094174, #0E6399);
-webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0px 1px 2px;
-moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0px 1px 2px;
box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0px 1px 2px;
position: relative;
z-index: 99999;
behavior: url(PIE.htc);
}
```

Can anyone please advise?

Comment: I've just checked it on iPad2 and it seems to be working - top navigation bar is displayed and I'm able to see subMenuItems by taping on menu item.

Comment: [Validate your HTML.](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fexamples.iamwebsitedeveloper.com%2Fjohn%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) You have mismatched tags and several duplicate `id` attributes. Debugging is useless until you fix these errors.

Answer (score 0):

Testing on original iPad and navigation looks and functions correctly with gradients and drop downs.  Try shutting down all your actively running iPad apps followed by a reboot. Although this would not explain the issue on 2 separate devices.  What IOS on the iPad?